# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x8C5\xB7\x9D\x11\xFD...' for laravel voyager cordinates input

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, voyager

I'm trying to add a cordinate input for a laravel [voyager](https://voyager.devdojo.com/) bread.

But I'm getting this issue when creating item.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value:
> '\x8C5\xB7\x9D\x11\xFD...' for column 'location' at row 1 (SQL: insert
> into `places` (`name`, `location`, `status`, `updated_at`,
> `created_at`) values (Reg 2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(79.9542002
> 7.0046719)'), INACTIVE, 2020-12-03 14:02:05, 2020-12-03 14:02:05))

I have this inside Place model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Spatial;

class Place extends Model
{
    use Spatial;
    protected $spatial = ['location'];
}
```

And **location** field is a **varchar column with 255 length**. Google map is available and I can select a place but when I submit the form I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like needed to add datatype in the table as **geometry**. Adding it in case anyone met with the same issue.